# gganimate: two layers with different geometries and timepoints

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64037373/1898713) question but here the two layers use different geometries, `geom_tile` and `geom_point`. The idea is to have tiles show up at different locations only in frames 2, 5, 8, and the point move along the diagonal in every frame.

When trying to run the following example, I get the error:

> Error: time data must be the same class in all layers

**Example**

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
require(gganimate)

# 3 tiles along x = 10-y; present at time points 2, 5, 8
dtP1 = data.table(x = c(1, 5, 9),
                  y = c(9, 5, 1),
                  t = c(2, 5, 8))

# 9 points along x=y; present at every time point
dtP2 = data.table(x = 1:9,
                  y = 1:9,
                  t = 1:9)

p = ggplot() +
    geom_tile(data = dtP1,
              aes(x = x,
                  y = y),
                  color = "#000000") +
    geom_point(data = dtP2,
               aes(x = x,
                   y = y),
               color = "#FF0000") +
    gganimate::transition_time(t) +
    gganimate::ease_aes('linear')

pAnim = gganimate::animate(p, 
                           renderer = av_renderer("~/test.mp4"), 
                           fps = 1, 
                           nframes = 9,
                           height = 400, width = 400)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
library(dplyr)

p <- rbind(dtP1 %>% mutate(group = "group1"),
           dtP2 %>% mutate(group = "group2")) %>%
  tidyr::complete(t, group) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_tile(data = . %>% filter(group == "group1"),
            color = "black") +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(group == "group2"),
             color = "red") +
  ggtitle("{frame_time}") + # added this to show the frame explicitly; optional
  transition_time(t) +
  ease_aes('linear')

animate(p, nframes = 9, fps = 1)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! So the secret is to have data for all time points in each layer, even if it's `NA`.